# Adding image as a parameter of a method

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a C# winform application with a database. In the database I have one DataTable called Airlines. The columns of this DataTable are "Name", "Country", "Telephone", "Email", "Logo".

I want to create a method to be used in Windows Form application. This method is going to be

`public int AddNewAirline (string name, string country, string telephone, string email, xxxxx)`

The parameters will be taken from Windows Form text boxes, and the logo by the Browse... option. I have created the method and the SQL operation is:

```
"INSERT INTO Airlines VALUES('"+name+"','....blah blah blah.... ¿but what about the logo? )";
```

So my main question, is: What parameter should I add on the `xxxxxx` part of the method header, and what the SQL operation should be like? I'm a bit messed with this and I couldn't find a solution on the Internet.

Comment: it depends on what about the image you want to save in the database.  Is it the path to the image or is it the actual bytes of the image?

Comment: Do you want to store the actual bytes of the image in the database or do you want to store a pointer to the image in the hard drive or in a server?

Comment: I have the path of the image that is found by browsing the folders of the computer. I think that's not the actual bytes, I think it's the other option. @mreyeros Murven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store the path to the image in the database, you can do it the same way you are saving the other parameters:

```
public int AddNewAirline (string name, string country, string telephone, string email, string logoPath)
```

You SQL insert statement is missing the column names. Try this:

```
"INSERT INTO Airlines ('Name', 'Country', 'Telephone', 'Email', 'Logo') " +
"VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + country + "', '" + telephone + "', '" + email + "', '" + logoPath + "')"
```

You should be aware that in taking this approach, the possibility exists that the image could be moved or deleted, leaving your database with a path to a file that no longer exists. In order to resolve this, you could make a copy of the image to a safe location and reference the copy in your database, or you could store the actual bytes of the image in your database as a BLOB.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked OK, I was thinking that nobody was going to answer. Thanks so much @Ben